# application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) not called on start up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, launching-application

When I kill the app by swiping up in the multi-app UI in the simulator and relaunch it the `application (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` method is not called, and every time just the login screen shows up. I do not understand what's going on and it really defeats the purpose of checking whether user is logged in or not from firebase if the method is not even called while launching the app again, would really appreciate some help! (Does this have something to do with SceneDelegate methods I am seeing, from what i understand the didFinishLaunching method should be called regardless when launching an application)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        print("---------appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called!---------------")
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = MainViewController()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

Here's the code for the MainViewController as requested

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
                if user == nil {
                    print("nil user -----------")
                    self.perform(#selector(self.showHomeController), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)
              } else {
                    print("non nil user --------")
                    self.perform(#selector(self.showWelcomeController), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)
              }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func showWelcomeController () {
        present(WelcomeViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func showHomeController () {
        present(HomeViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The ---------appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called!--------------- is printed only once, when the project is built and opened in simulator

Disclaimer: I'm very new in iOS app development.

Comment: Is that code _ever_ called?

Comment: Given that the logic for determining the initial VC is `MainViewController` it seems more likely that the issue is there rather than in the app delegate.  Show that code

Comment: @matt the code is called when the build succeeds and opens for the first time in simulator, isn't called when I kill the app and relaunch in the sim

Comment: @Paulw11 attached the code for MainViewController

Comment: @NamandD how do you "relaunch" the application in the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just the way you "relaunch in the sim". If you kill the app and then tap the app's icon in the simulator, you are no longer running in Xcode; you are running independently. So you don't get *any* debugging any more; no `print` messages appear in the Xcode console, you don't stop at breakpoints, etc.

The solution is: relaunch by telling Xcode to build and run again, not by tapping the app's icon in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for responding @matt, even without the debugging I was expecting to see the user land directly on the home screen instead of the welcome screen, based on the combined code in appDelegate method and MainViewController, which i'm not getting. Just trying to understand why that's the case. Thanks

Comment: I'm totally with you! But the form of your question was "appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called! is printed only once", and so that's what I explained to you.

Comment: The reason why the MainViewController doesn't run the `addStateDidChangeListener` is probably that the state _didn't_ change. I don't really know anything about Firebase but that's my guess.

Answer (score 0):

The action of swiping up and killing the application breaks the debugger link. So if you relaunch the application by clicking on the app itself in the simulator, you will no longer have a debugger link with Xcode. That is the reason why you don't see the messages being printed anymore.

You have to relaunch from Xcode to get the launch messages printed once again.

If you have other questions please post them separately. It will be easier to track and respond to by everyone.

Comment: The thing is, even for the first time when the app is launched in the simulator it doesn't show the MainViewController's screen. I tried putting in the delay so that the screen may be visible but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I was responding to your titular question about didFinishLaunchingWithOptions no being called on subsequent manual relaunches. If you have other questions please post them separately. It will be easier to track and respond to by everyone.